# How to post JSON data in MVC Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to post json objects to MVC in visual studio 2015 preview. However, the data doesn't seem to bind to the action methods parameter. There used to be a JsonValueProviderFactory registered in previous versions of MVC that handled this but I cannot seem to find it in MVC6? Has the setup changed, this used to work out-of-the box in previous versions?

Basically I have a controller method

```
public ActionResult Save(Person person)
{
   ...
}
```

Which I'm trying to call from javascript:

```
var personData = { Name : 'John Doe' };
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Content("~/Person/Save")',
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(personData ), 
        dataType: "json", 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    })
```

In previous versions of MVC, the json object was mapped to the c# parameter, 
see this article for example http://webcognoscere.com/post/How-to-POST-a-JSON-object-to-a-Controller-Action.aspx

Comment: Show us some code? What build of MVC are you using (show your project.json)?

Comment: You are right, I have updated the post. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Preview (I'm not sure the exact build that was shipped)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `[FromBody]` to the parameter. In MVC 6 the logic from MVC and Web API was merged into one system. This means that contents that need to be deserialized as JSON from the body of a post need to explicitly noted in the action method's parameter:

```
public ActionResult Save([FromBody] Person person)
{
    ...
}
```